# Using Spring DSL in a Grails Plugin

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, proxy, javabeans

I'm trying to use the Spring DSL functionality in a Grails plugin.  However, it doesn't work.  Here's what I have in my plugin's conf/spring/resources.groovy file:

```
import org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
  baseSvcProxy(ScopedProxyFactoryBean) {
    targetBeanName = 'baseService'
    proxyTargetClass = true
  }
}
```

However, it seems to be completely ignored.  If I move the exact same code to the application's conf/spring/resources.groovy file everything works perfectly.  Is there something that needs to be done differently for plugins for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to modify the spring context from a Grails plugin you need to use the doWithSpring section of your plugin by [hooking into the runtime configuration](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html#hookingIntoRuntimeConfiguration). Resources.groovy is ignored in plugins.